# Camera app on android open souce?

Tags: android

Is the Camera app on android open source?
I have installed android 4.0.3 emulator and get the camera app source. But when I run it, it only let me set the exposure. But when I run Camera app on Galaxy Nexus, the camera app let me set more than exposure, it let me set white balance, flash mode.

My question is why the Camera app on emulator and Galaxy Nexus phone is different?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since its more of a guess.. But I'm assuming the Camera activity has some smarts that help it determine what the device does and does not support in terms of image capturing which is why you see different options for each.

Comment: should be the same app - device capabilities (and therefore the options you have to customize) depend on device driver / hardware. Emulator is just doing some very basic emulation of the camera. [Camera.html#getParameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getParameters%28%29) determines what options you have.